# jQuery/ajax won't send post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to get jQuery to send the content of a textarea to update a record but it won't. When I change the value of the textarea so that it begins with a number then it sends fine. I can verify that the content is handed to the JS function successfully by using alert(), but it won't get to the PHP file. All other JS functions work fine.

Edited to add more code which may be relevant.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function add_vid(t) {
    if ($('#vref').val().length <5) return;
    var vref = $('#vref').val();
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'inc/ajax.php',
      data: { 'a':'add_vid', 't':'<?=$_SESSION['t']?>', 'vref':vref},
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#add_vid_status').html('Adding...');
      },
      success:function(data){
            if (data == 'added') {
            $('#add_vid_status').html('Added');
            $('#vid_list').prepend('<div align="center" class="vid">'+vref+'</div>');
            $('#vref').val('');
        }
        else $('#add_vid_status').html('Error');
      },
      error:function(){
        $('#add_vid_status').html('Error');
      }
    });
  }
function del_vid(id) {
    var confirmdel = confirm('Delete ?');
    if (confirmdel) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'inc/ajax.php',
      data: { 'a':'del_vid', 't':'<?=$_SESSION['t']?>', 'id':id},
      success:function(data){
            if (data == 'deleted') {
                $("#v"+id).hide(900);
        }
      },
      error:function(){
        //$("#"+msg_id+'_a').html('error');
      }
    });
    }
    return false;
}
function update_vid(id) {
    vref = $("#update"+id).val();
    alert(vref);
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'inc/ajax.php',
          data: { 'a':'update_vid', 't':'<?=$_SESSION['t']?>', 'id':id, 'vref':vref},
          success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                if (data == 'updated') {
                    $("#if"+id).html(vref);
            }
          },
          error:function(){
            //$("#"+msg_id+'_a').html('error');
          }
        });
        return false;
}
function move_vid(id,dir) {
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'inc/ajax.php',
      data: { 'a':'move_vid', 't':'<?=$_SESSION['t']?>', 'id':id,'dir':dir},
      success:function(data){
            pos = data.split('_');
            pos_from = pos[0];
            pos_to = pos[1];
            //$("#if"+id).hide();
            if ($("#pos"+pos_to).length) {//if the id2 is on page (and not on a different paginated page) - swap them on-screen
                temp_html = $("#pos"+pos_from).html();
                $("#pos"+pos_from).html($("#pos"+pos_to).html());
                $("#pos"+pos_to).html(temp_html);
                temp_html = null;
            }
            else $("#pos"+pos_from).html('<div>Video moved off page.<br> Reload to see the result.</div>');
            //$("#if"+id).fadeIn(400);
      },
      error:function(){
        //$("#"+msg_id+'_a').html('error');
      }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="vref" cols="55" rows="3" id="vref" placeholder="Video embed code"></textarea>
 <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add_vid('<?=$_SESSION['t']?>')"> <span id="add_vid_status"></span>

<input type="button" value="update" onClick="update_vid(27)">
<textarea cols="65" rows="3" id="update27"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789?byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></textarea>
```

PHP code:

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['auth'] != 1 || $_POST['t'] != $_SESSION['t']) exit();
elseif (isset($_POST['a'])) {
    require_once('cfg.php');
    db_connect();
    if ($_POST['a'] == 'add_vid' && strlen($_POST['vref'])>4) {
        //ADDS VIDEO TO DB AND ECHOES "added"
    }
    elseif ($_POST['a'] == 'del_vid' && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        //DELETES VIDEO AND ECHOES "deleted"
    }
    elseif ($_POST['a'] == 'update_vid' && is_numeric($_POST['id']) && strlen($_POST['vref']>4)) {
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
        //echo 'PHP: '.$_POST['vref']; (here i can test if the argument reaches.)
        $vref = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vref']);
        $q = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos` SET `vref`='{$vref}' WHERE `id`={$id}") or die ('update error: '.mysql_error());
        if ($q) echo 'updated';
    }
    // CODE GOES ON...
}
?>
```

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/). Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Can you catch the POST in your PHP environment? I think it may be more a problem with what is being parsed on the back end than what is being posted by ajax here.

Comment: I can confirm that the POST doesn't reach the PHP environment at all. It is baffling me that just by adding a single number in front of the whole iframe code (my content) it works just fine!

Comment: @mustafa that indeed doesn't make any sense at all. There must be some code we're missing here that causes this.

Comment: What is `'#if' + id`? The `#` symbol is for ids, which have to be unique. Where are you planning to insert the code? You should define a `<div id="response_box"></div>` and in the `success()` method use `$('#response_box').html(vref);`

Comment: I have several videos on a page. Each video (embed code) has its own iframe area, so they are named uniquely such as if27. That way, when the PHP returns "updated" then this iframe div will update with the new embed code

Comment: @mustafa is it only the `update_vid` function which is having problems, or the others as well? Did you already try changing to double quotes for `$_SESSION["t"]` in your Javascript?

Comment: yes, i tried with double quotes as well as without the Session check altogether. it is just the `update_vid` which is behaving unexpectedly unless the content handed to it begins with a number such as `1<iframe ...` All other functions are happily working with the `$_SESSION['t']`

Comment: @mustafa I can't see any direct issues besides that then. I guess you'll have to try debugging by `echo`ing and `console.log`ging variables within your functions and see if there are any unexpected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After abandoning the update feature, yesterday when I wanted to copy the code for a similar project I noticed the glaring mistake in the PHP code where I am checking the string length: I had written `strlen($_POST['vref']>4)` instead of `strlen($_POST['vref'])>4`. After
correcting this it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your Ajax data object:

```
't':'<?=$_SESSION['t']?>'
```

You use the same type of quotes twice, so Javascript thinks that `t` is a variable, and doesn't recognise it. Changing your quotes like this fixes the error that your code was throwing:

```
't':'<?=$_SESSION["t"]?>'
```

Otherwhise, if you *did* mean for this to be a variable, you need to use it as following:

```
't':'<?=$_SESSION["'+ t +'"]?>'
```

Comment: If this answer does not fix your issue, please add some more information in your question, such as your PHP code.

Comment: Shouldn't you echo the `$_SESSION` variable here?

Comment: @JayBlanchard `<?=$foo?>` is actually a [shorthand notation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for `echo`.

Comment: I understand that @DarkAshelin, but the use of the short tag here, along with badly formatted quotes, is likely causing a lot of confusion for the OP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Possibly, but it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: True, we're hardly sure what is relevant at this point because the OP has not returned to answer any questions.

Comment: sorry guys, I was not expecting such quick response for which I am very grateful. Please don't let the $_SESSION confuse you as this simply equates to t: '12345' when viewed from the browser-side. So I can confirm that my single quotes INSIDE PHP is not interfering with JS ones